# How can I use map to return a nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want to do, using map, is pretty plain.

I want to call this:

```
<Striper size={3} text={"Hey everybody!"}/>
```

To get this:

```
<>
  <Stripe>
    <Stripe>
      <Stripe>
        Hey everybody!
      </Stripe>
    </Stripe>
  </Stripe>
</>
```

I tried this way, but it fails:

```
const Striper = (props) => {
    const contentTop=props.sizer.map((item)=> <Stripe>)
    const contentBottom=props.sizer.map((item)=> </Stripe>)

    return (
        <div>
          {contentTop}
          {contentBottom}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Basically only this works (which isn't what I want):

```
const contentTop = props.sizer.map((item)=> <Stripe></Stripe>)
```

How could I get what I want?

Comment: Use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead.

Comment: You are not passing in an array on which you are trying to use Array methods on.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that the way I'm really calling it in the code is:

    const arr=Array(6).fill(1);    
    return (
        <div>
          <Striper sizer={arr} colors={colours}/>

Comment: I posted an answer using similar code, see if that fits your needs

Comment: Thank you Emile, after struggling a bit more I finally figured it out, w/reducer being the key to the solution:     const content=props.sizer.reduce((total,currentValue)=> <Stripe color={props.colors}>{total}</Stripe>), called like this, simplified version: const arr=Array(6).fill("this is my text!"); <Striper sizer={arr} colors={colours}/>

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being really simple (thank you, [Emile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963307/how-can-i-use-map-to-return-a-nested-object/57963427#comment102337793_57963307)): use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

As it says in the documentation about reduce, it's really useful when you need only one thing returned. And that's what I needed.

As [I said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963307/how-can-i-use-map-to-return-a-nested-object/57963427#comment102338372_57963427):

> What I want to return from `<App size={2} text="Hello"/>` is really
>   `<Stripe><Stripe>Hello</Stripe></Stripe>`, but because I have to
>   return a whole object, the closest I can come with map is
>   `<Stripe>Hello</Stripe><Stripe>Hello</Stripe>`.

So instead, use reduce.

This is the solution, verified to work. (Note: I'm being somewhat handwavey about `size={3}` when it's actually an array, because I know how to do that stuff, it isn't my question but you can see my implementation in the answer below).

```
const Striper = (props) => {
  const content = props.sizer.reduce(
    (total, currentValue) => <Stripe color={props.colors}>{total}</Stripe>
  )    
  return (
    <div>
      {content}          
    </div>
  )
}
```

And as it's actually called:

```
const arr = Array(6).fill("this is my text!");    
return (
  <div>
    <Striper sizer={arr} colors={colours}/>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can achieve something like with this approach:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const Stripe = () => <span> – </span>

const App = ({ size, text }) => {
  const arrFromNum = Array.from(Array(size), (x, i) => i + 1)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {arrFromNum.map(x => <Stripe />)}
      {text}
      {arrFromNum.map(x => <Stripe />)}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

render(<App size={4} text="Hello" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Wouldn't this have size Stripe components before and after? I think he wants them nested.

Comment: @DillanWilding You're right, this doesn't nest them. Probably overlooked it. If the OP  doesn't have a solution yet, please do tell. I'll be more then happy to revise my answer!

Comment: Thank you for this - I've studied it, but as Dillan said, it isn't nested. What I want to return from <App size={2} text="Hello"/> is really <Stripe><Stripe>Hello</Stripe></Stripe>, but because I have to return a whole object, the closest I can come is <Stripe>Hello</Stripe><Stripe>Hello</Stripe>. I think I need a recursive call of some sort, but I'm stumped as to how to write it.

Comment: I finally figured it out, w/reducer being the key to the solution: const content=props.sizer.reduce((total,currentValue)=> <Stripe color={props.colors}>{total}</Stripe>), called like this, simplified version: const arr=Array(6).fill("this is my text!"); <Striper sizer={arr} colors={colours}/>

Comment: @jumar it's highly encouraged to write an answer to your own question and accept it  (after some time).

Comment: Ok; I'll answer it, shortly.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one possible way of many different possibilities based on your scenario:

`<Striper size={3} text={"Hey everybody!"}/>`

`export default ({ size, text }) => <><Stripe size={size} /> {text} <Stripe size={size} /></>;`

`export default ({ size }) => <>{ Array(size).fill().map(_ => <h3>Stripe!</h3>) }</>;`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tnqv2k

Comment: Thank you (though I ended up using a different solution, see my comments above).